# Passing multiple values to arduino from python

Tags: python, c, arrays, arduino

I am currently trying to pass multiple values from a python script to an arduino. The values are passed over the serial port.

In the python code, we need to be able to send the Arduino 4 values, x, y, z and a hex colour over serial..
On the arduino I am trying to store the 4 sent values into the 4 seperate arrays. The 3 xyz arrays seem to get the correct values and store them, but im having trouble handling the colour value being passed from the python script. Im able to see the payload is being sent for the x,y,z (1 payload each as 1 or 2 byte's being sent as expected). But the colour payload is being sent over 4 or 6 payloads. Im guessing this is because it is a much larger value. Im having trouble sending those colour payloads to the colourRGB array and then after receiving them all, appending the values back together again in the processColour() method to be passed to the setTheLED() method.

The toned down python script is here:

```html
data0= data[0]['x']+", "+data[0]['y']+", "+data[0]['z']+", "+data[0]['colour']
#print data0
data0x = str(data[0]['x'])
data0y = str(data[0]['y'])
data0z = str(data[0]['z'])
data0c = str(data[0]['colour'])

##################################################################
                                                            #MAIN
port = 'COM7' #check this is right every time

#delays are here to stope data being lost before written over serial
def main(val):
    ser = serial.Serial(port) #gets serial port
    time.sleep(1.5)
    ser.write('#')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    ser.write(val) #writes value over serial
    time.sleep(1.5)
    ser.write('*')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    ser.close() #close the port

##################################################################
                                                                #MENU#

def menu():
    #menu for testing input to duino
    print 'CUBES AVAILABLE: '
    print '1: CUBE 1'
    print '5: QUIT'
    return input("ENTER ONE OF THESE OPTIONS: ")

loop=True
choice=0
while loop:
    choice=menu()
    if choice == 1:
        main(data0x)
        main(data0y)
        main(data0z)
        main(data0c)
    elif choice == 5:
        print 'QUITTING'
        break
```

Here is the code on the arduino, edited.

```html
#include <Rainbowduino.h>

unsigned long colorRGB[100] = {};
unsigned int posX[100] = {};
unsigned int posY[100] = {};
unsigned int posZ[100] = {};
unsigned int endCount = 0;          //end of message counter
unsigned int payloadCount = 0;      //actual payload counter
unsigned int startCount = 0;        //begin message counter

void setup() {
    Rb.init();
    Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}


void loop() {
    char incomingData;   // for incoming serial data
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {        // Check for incoming Serial Data
        incomingData = Serial.read();


        //  check for start of message
        if (incomingData == '#') {
            Rb.setPixelZXY(0, 0, 0, 0x00FF00); //green
            startCount++;
            delay(333);
            Rb.blankDisplay();
        }

        //  check for end of message
        if (incomingData == '*') {
            Rb.setPixelZXY(1, 0, 0, 0xFF0000); //red
            endCount++;
            delay(333);
            Rb.blankDisplay();
        }

        // if data not * or # then must be payload
        if (incomingData != '*' && incomingData != '#') {
            Rb.setPixelZXY(2, 0, 0, 0xFFFF00); //yellow
            payloadCount++;
            colorRGB[payloadCount] = incomingData; //set incoming data value to  count pos
            delay(333);
            Rb.blankDisplay();//clear

        }
    }
    delay(100);
    //this is where I want to read the value from colourRGB[] and "setTheLED()"
    if (payloadCount >= 6) {
        setTheLED();
    }
}


void setTheLED() {
    Rb.setPixelZXY(3, 3, 3, processTheColour());
}


//  This is my attempt at reading the values in the colourRGB
//  array and appending each value to "temp"
long processTheColour() {
    unsigned long temp;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp += colorRGB[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```